# Django with "email as username" has conflict with facebook login?! Or how to have both 

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-views, email

For the first phase, I used Email as username [django-email-as-username](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username). For the second phase, I would like to activate facebook login as well. But almost all of the 3rd party apps that I've seen are using Django's **username** as a backend.

Do you have any idea that which of them are adaptable with the way that I have mentioned before ?

ANY help is highly appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting allows for a list of backends so that you can support multiple methods of authentication: username/password, email/password, facebook, twitter, openid, etc

[django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) for instance defines a new backend per authentication provider. This works fine along side other authentication backends.

Comment: Thanks.. since this App has some problems with python 2.7.3, and I'm new to social apps, do you have any idea on django-allauth as well ? https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth 
Apparently it works without any problem with python 2.7.3

Comment: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is a part of `django.contrib.auth`. All of these social apps make use of this feature and should work with other auth backends.